# Select from three tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables where `table_2` is the middle(connected) between `table_1` and `table_3`

tables

```
table_id
...
...
```

table_rest

```
rest_id
table_id
...
```

rest

```
rest_id
...
...
```

And the query to select I use

```
SELECT m.table_id, table_name
        FROM tables m 
        JOIN table_rest mr 
        ON m.table_id = mr.table_id 
        WHERE rest_id = '$rest_id'
```

What I need now is to join in this query another table `reserv`

```
id
...
status
```

To check if status is `0`, `1`,or `2` to not show me anything if there is no status this mean there is no record to show me. In other words this is resserved system where I show on screen few tables. If status is 0,1,2 thats mean the table is taken. If nothing is found for status this mean that there is no record for table and can be shown to user.

**EDIT: Sample scenario**

`tables`

```
table_id
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
```

`rest`

```
rest_id
   1
   2
```

`table_rest`

```
table_id | rest_id
   1         2
   2         2
   3         2
   4         2
   5         2
```

So the query that is above will generate `5 tables for rest_id=2` and none for `rest_id=1`
So now I have another table

`reserv`

```
id | status
 1     0
 2     1
 3     2
```

So in this table `reserv` currently are saved 3 tables. The idea is to show me other two whit `id=4` and `id=5` because they are not in table `reserv` and don't have any status.

Hope is a little bit more clear now.

Comment: Please provide some sample data along with the desired result.

Comment: What exactly you want me to provide?

Comment: sample data for each table and expected result based on the sample data.

Comment: How `reserv` is related to `table_id` ?

Comment: There I store reservations I store `table_id`

Comment: Still did not get.. when you join any of the table to `reserv` then you need to have a joining key. Say you are joining `table` with `reserv` which is the joining key in `reserv`

Comment: That would be row `status`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to point from table reserv to which table is beign booked, let's call it reserv.table_id

```
SELECT m.table_id, table_name
        FROM tables m 
        JOIN table_rest mr 
        ON m.table_id = mr.table_id 
        left join reserv
        on reserv.table_id = m.id
        WHERE rest_id = '$rest_id'
        and reserv.status is null   (*note)
```

***note** use 'is' or 'is not' depending of your needs, as far as I read, first seems that you want !=, later that what you want is =

Comment: So in first option suggest that I must put in table_rest another row `status` which point to `status` in `reserv`. Am I right?

Comment: Notice that table 1 from rest 1 shouldn't be the same that table 1 from rest 2, for instance.

Comment: No, you could do that.. .but if you have no more relevant data in table reserv there is no need, put the data directly (status 0,1 or 2) directly in table_rest and no need to use the table reserv (you could delete it)

Comment: I have data in reserv along with status. I have name, phone etc. The main idea is when user open page `make reservation` to show only the free tables. Those that are not taken ( that are not with status 0,1,2).

Comment: Then use option 2, or as you said, instead of creating a new field id in table_res, you can already use the field status :)

Comment: Can you clarify me a little part two and this `Create an index 'id' for table_rest and make the id of table reserv a foreign key for that index`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66560/discussion-between-vivoconunxino-and-goro).

Answer (score 2):

It's better if you provide sample data or `sqlfiddle`. Based on what I realize: Is this what you want:

```
select tables.table_id, rest.rest_id
from tables
left join table_rest on table_rest.table_id = tables.table_id
left join rest on rest.rest_id = table_rest.rest_id
where rest.rest_id = '$rest_id'
and tables.table_id not in (select id from reserv)
```

Comment: You don't have anything for `reserv` in the query. I will try to make it in sqlfiddle

Comment: `and tables.table_id not in (select id from reserv)` I need to select tables that are not in reserv. Check table `tables` and to show me thoose tables that are not in `reserv`